# Формат архива наподобие tar, но с очень быстрым получением папок верхнего уровня

Tags: linux, архивация, tar

Подскажите, пожалуйста, формат архива наподобие tar, чтобы имея большой архив (>10ГБ) с большим числом папок, файлов и уровней вложенностей папок, в следующем use case:

1. открыть архив
2. увидеть список файлов и папок верхнего уровня
3. перейти в одну из папок + аналогично (2)
4. повторить пункт (3) несколько раз
5. выбрать некоторую папку и распакавать её в выбранное местоположение

все пункты кроме (5) выполнялись очень быстро (что-нибудь вроде `O(число видимых пользователю элементов на экране)`).

---

Формат tar почти подходит, за исключением того, что пункт (1) выполняется очень долго, насколько я понимаю в процессе открытия архива строится индекс всех папок и файлов, но в моём use case это не нужно.

Comment: Файловая система?

Comment: @avp нет, нужно именно что-то вроде архива, чтобы был один файл

Comment: Не знаю, есть ли такие в реальности, но могу легко представить реализацию  на [fuse](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUSE_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0)), когда мы будем монтировать вместо девайса (скажем, флешки) регулярный файл

Comment: Стандартный zip хранит список файлов в отдельном индексе так что хождение по «дереву» должно быть мгновенным

Comment: ну, т.е., требуется, чтобы сначала в архиве было оглавление, а затем содержимое файлов. фактически — отсутствие возможности **быстро**, без перезаписывания всего архива, добавлять новые файлы. на вскидку, что вспомнилось: [iso 9660](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660), [xar](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xar_(%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Остановился на [squashfs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashfs)

[Инструкция](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html):

- создать архив:

  ```
  mksquashfs <папка_для_архивирования> <имя_архива>
  ```
- открыть архив (путём монтирования его в некоторую папку с последующей работой с этой папкой)

  ```
  mount <имя_архива> /mnt/whatever -t squashfs -o loop
  ```
- закрыть архив

  ```
  umount /mnt/whatever
  ```

### Другие возможные архиваторы

- [`zip`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP) не подходит, так как [не умеет в юникод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833497/268670)
- [`dar`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAR_(%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)) ([статья на хабре](https://habr.com/post/215449/)) подходит, <sub>но мне не понравился внешний вид программы для распаковки архивов</sub>
- [`xar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xar_(archiver)) вероятно подходит, но я не очень разобрался какой программой предполагается осуществлять random access (стандартная kde-шная (ark) вроде бы всё равно сначала строит полный индекс)
- ещё встречал упоминание `fusecompress`, но не разбирался как он работает

### Дополнительные комментарии

- В интернете много информации по данному вопросу, искать надо по запросу [tar random access](https://google.ru/search?q=tar+random+access)
- В статье Википедии [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) есть целый [раздел, посвящённый данной проблеме](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Random_access)
- Кажется, существуют расширения `tar`, позволяющие выполнять random access read ([например](https://github.com/lpryszcz/tar_indexer))

### Связанные вопросы на английских SO

- [Compression formats with good support for random access within archives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/429987/5812238)
- [Print archive file list instantly (without decompressing entire archive)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287087/199096)
- [Browsable compressed filesystem archive with full attributes?](https://superuser.com/q/204681/734823)
- [Archive for root file system with quick random access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244604/199096)