# Архивирование файлов с юникод-именами с помощью команды zip в linux

Tags: linux, zip, архивация

Как создать архив с помощью команды [zip](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html), если имена файлов содержат символы юникода?

---

Создал пустой файл с именем из одного символа ★ (U+2605), пробую архивировать его:

```
zip archive ★ -UN=UTF8
```

получаю ошибку:

```
zip error: Internal logic error (empty name without -j or -r)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятнее всего используется версия `zip`'а с [патчем natspec](http://www.opennet.ru/tips/info/2494.shtml).

Он предусматривает включение флага DOS-совместимости по умолчанию и ключ `-K` для его отключения. Но, к сожалению, в патче, судя по всему, баг: имена файлов перекодируются в dos-кодировку независимо от флага.

Варианты решения/дальнейших действий:

- Собрать zip без данного патча.
- Подправить патч и пересобрать zip самостоятельно.
- Связаться с автором патча.
- Связаться с багзиллой своего дистрибутива (лучше после одного из двух предыдущих пунктов).
- И (по случаю скорой 29-й годовщины zip'а и 27-й юникода) не создавать zip-архивы с именами файлов в кодировке, которая моложе самого формата.